# Dont show 0% data labels in excel but show -0.1% and +0.1%

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I've managed to hide data labels with 0% by using the number format 0.0%;; but need to show -0.2% and that's been removed - how do i hide 0% but show +0/1% and -0.1%?

Answer (score 0):

Use conditional formatting (e.g. color of text), rather than setting the numeric format. Setting text the same color as cell background or replacing "0.0%" with a space might be used. See https://support.office.com/client/Use-a-formula-to-apply-conditional-formatting-fed60dfa-1d3f-4e13-9ecb-f1951ff89d7f or http://www.contextures.com/xlCondFormat03.html for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Your number format should be "0.0%;-0.0%;"
As it is, you're telling it to show positive numbers and hide both negative and zero values
Take a look at [Microsoft's Custom Number Format explanation](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/create-a-custom-number-format-HP010342372.aspx)
The order for a custom format is "[POSITIVE];[NEGATIVE];[ZERO];[TEXT]"